# How to using a vue plugin in script setup?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, inertiajs

I'm trying to access a vue plugin in my script setup, as follow:

Creating a Inertia App

```
import { i18nVue } from 'laravel-vue-i18n'

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        const the_app = createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(i18nVue, {
                resolve: lang => require(`../../lang/${lang}.json`),
            })
            .mixin({ methods: { 
                route,
            } })
            .provide('appLocale', appLang)
            .provide('i18nVue', {
                resolve: lang => require(`../../lang/${lang}.json`),
            })

        the_app.mount(el)

        document.getElementById('app_loader').remove()

    },
})
```

Is able to access in template:

`<PageHeader :title="$t('Calendário')" />`

But in  I need to do like this to use the plugin, for example:

```
const translate = getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties.$t
const title = translate('Calendário')
```

I'm not sure if is a good pratice call getCurrentInstance() and I imagine that there is another way to bring $t() to script setup.

I tried to send data from  to  e try to use .provide em createApp to pass the plugin, but didn't work

Comment: "if is a good pratice call getCurrentInstance()" - no, it's the last resort but is acceptable as lazy implementation for custom composable. You can see here https://github.com/xiCO2k/laravel-vue-i18n/blob/main/src/index.ts#L120-L124 that it could be implemented as `useI18n = () => inject('i18n')`, as the lib doesn't have it yet